# How to superimpose the colormap on dicom image

Tags: matlab

I want to superimpose the color map on dicom image for showing the difference from different part in the brain.

To make color map smooth, I had use interp2() so the dimension sizes are bigger.

And size of dicom image is 256 by 256, the size of color map is 2560 by 2560.

[this is a color map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJSYH.jpg)

[this is a dicom image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m70xz.jpg)

```
Ori = new_conc_tNAA;
[x,y]=meshgrid(1:1:16);
[xi,yi]=meshgrid(1:0.00586:16);
z=interp2(x,y,Ori,xi,yi,'linear');
alphamask=z>0;
figure,hnd=imagesc(z);
set(hnd,'AlphaData',alphamask);
title(sprintf("Original"));

max_conc=max(max(new_conc_tNAA));
colormap(jet)
caxis([0 max_conc]);
colorbar
```

the code to show the color map.

I don't know how to correctly overlay a color map on a dicom image.

[This is the result I want to get .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZ7bK.png)

Comment: what is the actual problem? can you attach your image and the code?

Comment: what are you expecting from this overlay? The colormap jet is a matrix 64-by-3 and represents 64 RGB colors.

Comment: the color map shows the concentration of metabolic in different part of brain . This overlay can help me observe the distribution of the concentration.

Comment: You mean there is an original grey scaled picture and a colored picture with some colored regions (depending on some threshold). and you want to put this colored pictured on the original one. Did I get it correctly? Maybe you can show an example from the Internet?

Comment: Yes, your explanation is almost right.But the colored picture is color map, I am not sure whether different method or result if you think the color map as a picture to make them overlap.